# Remove background shading from Seaborn lineplot

Tags: python, seaborn

This is my code

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 30))
sns.lineplot(data=dataframe, x='A', y='B', hue='C', ax=ax)
```

This was the result:
[image: what I don't want]
There is a blue line and it is painted in light blue as if it spreads around it.

I only want to see the color of the straight line.

Like this, for example:

[image: What I want]

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the confidence interval that you see. You can supress it by passing `ci=None`:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 30))
sns.lineplot(data=dataframe, x='A', y='B', hue='C', ax=ax, ci=None)
```